# Unusual Subversion Folders Appeared After Update

Tags: svn

I have been using Subversion for about 2 years to manage a large C# project. On a recent Subversion update, a number of new folders were added to my source code folder:

\conf
\db
\locks
\hooks

35+ files were also added during the update, all appearing under the 4 new folders.

I haven't changed any client (I use TortoiseSVN) or server software related to Subversion, so I'm puzzled why these folders and files were suddenly introduced.  It also seems strange that files seemingly related to the internal workings of Subversion are now part of my source code repository.

Can anyone shed some light on why this happened?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The folders you list (conf, db, locks, hooks) are folders from the repository directory that lives on the SVN server.  Most likely someone accidentally right-clicked and did a "TortoiseSVN->Create Repository Here".  Should be able to determine who did it by checking the SVN log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that's exactly what happened!

Answer (score 3):

Check the project history to make sure that somebody *else* hasn't accidentally added the contents of the actual repository directory to the repository itself. That's the only thing I can think of that would cause that to happen - it's highly unlikely to be a failure within Subversion itself.