# Subversion Repository has weird files in it

Tags: database, svn, format, tortoisesvn

I am managing a TortoiseSVN application rollout for a number of software developers.

An administrator has created a test repository for me to test before rollout and there are a number of directories here that I didn't create (or at least I don't remember) nor do I have access to modify the files in those directories.

Here are the directories:  conf, db, format and hooks

There was a post were someone else ran into something like this (however I don't have enough posts to make a comment to their post, so had to create a new post).

[Unusual Subversion Folders Appeared After Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763453/unusual-subversion-folders-appeared-after-update)

I'm not understanding how a repository could have been created to the Subversion server from TortoiseSVN.  I don't have access to the server, just the application.  I'm not able to right-click from Windows7 and the TortoiseSVN Repository Browser and create a new repository within a repository.

And can I go ahead and remove these files and not cause any issues?

Comment: Did the administrator who set up the repository add them?

Comment: The admin must have created the repository, you need to check with your admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the directories: conf, db, format and hooks

It's server-side tree, you have don't worry about it, because for client-side usage you have to know (as SVN-admin tell about it) **only URL of repository**, how it correlate with physical tree on server **isn't your question and headache**

> how a repository could have been created to the Subversion server from TortoiseSVN

No ways. TortoiseSVN is **pure client-side tool**, creating repository is **server-side administrative job** (unless you have some server's space mounted as local drive, in which on any **empty folder** you can use `Create repository here`)

```
>dir /b /s
z:\Repo
```

`Create repository here` magic on `z:\Repo` casted

```
>dir /b /s
z:\Repo
z:\Repo\locks
z:\Repo\hooks
z:\Repo\conf
z:\Repo\README.txt
z:\Repo\db
z:\Repo\format
z:\Repo\svn.ico
...
```

but from client side it's just

```
>svn ls -R -v file:///Z:/Repo
      1 Badger                июн 28 01:19 ./
      1 Badger                июн 28 01:19 branches/
      1 Badger                июн 28 01:19 tags/
      1 Badger                июн 28 01:19 trunk/
```

> can I go ahead and remove these files and not cause any issues?

It depends. There you get these files? Inside Working Copy?

Comment: I can check with the SVN Admin and see why those directories are there.                                                                                                                                  However from the TortoiseSVN Repository Browser it shows my user id as the Author for those directories.  And to test, I created a Repository under C:\Temp and it created the same directories as show on the Repository Server.

Comment: @user3783793 - yes, it created and must create it: it's **server-side physical presentation** of repo, while you must use only **client-side logical presentation** of repo (for `C:\Temp` here) `file:///C:/Temp` and SVN (not OS) commands